# Unable to sync Salesforce campaigns to xConnect

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, campaigncreator, salesforce-connect

I'm trying to sync the `Salesforce campaigns` to `xConnect` using the Sitecore's predefined pipeline batch (`Salesforce Campaigns to xConnect Sync`).

From the logs, I find that the data is successfully fetched from the Salesforce. This is the log when I run the pipeline batch -

```
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:17 INFO [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline batch processing. (pipeline batch: Salesforce Campaigns to xConnect Sync)
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:18 INFO [Data Exchange] Condition added to read objects modified on or after 12/31/2017 6:30:00 PM. (pipeline: Read Campaigns from Salesforce, pipeline step: Read Salesforce Campaigns, pipeline step identifier: 30c88b95-9c9b-4cac-94b8-a2d2061cf3db, object: campaign)
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:19 INFO [Data Exchange] Definition batch was successfully submitted. (pipeline: Process Single Campaign, pipeline step: Add Reference Data Definition to Batch, pipeline step identifier: 79164044-afc0-4a41-84d3-4273534497d3, thread id: 0, batch size: 5)
ManagedPoolThread #8 13:41:19 INFO [Data Exchange] Definition batch was successfully submitted. (pipeline: Read Campaigns from Salesforce, pipeline step: Submit Reference Data Batch, pipeline step identifier: 462073f0-9227-4589-8e2c-fd1de1822877, thread id: 0, batch size: 1)
```

But I couldn't find the data either in the reporting database or in the `Experience analytics` section of the Sitecore instance. Where can I exactly find the synced data?

[image: Sitecore- ExperienceAnalytics]

Comment: It looks like there some problem in reporting/processing, could you please make sure both are working and services are also running?

Comment: Hi @MahendraShekhawat,
I see that both the services are running.
Any idea on where can I find the campaign data in the database?